# recursive search in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with credit card customers.  A customer has lost their card many times but their original account number has not followed them.  I have account_number which is current and I can pull back for several years.  I have original_acct and several xref accounts.  I have made two columns, one with account number, the second is customer_ref which has any number that has every been associated with that account.  The issue I am unable to solve is this, this example references a customer that lost their card twice:
card 101 is associated to 102, 102 is associated to 103, but 103 has no link to 101.  I want to add a column orig_acct.  It doesn't matter what number is in the column, 101,102,103.  The first one is nice but it can be any, so that if I search for that number I will get the entire history.

Column 1 and 2 in the table below are what I have, column three represents what I want.  This shows two customers that have both needed replacement cards several times.  The way I look at it is a links b, b links c, but c doesn't always link to a.  Self joins in sql go so far but don't work.  I tried a hash table but I'm inexperienced and not getting there.  Graph theory in R works but it's not an option at this client.

```
account_num customer_ref orig_cust
1260 1260 1260
1260 2099 1260
1260 7104 1260
7104 1260 1260
7104 2099 1260
7104 7104 1260
1317 2537 1317
1317 1317 1317
1317 2216 1317
1317 0219 1317
2216 4077 1317
2216 2216 1317
2216 2703 1317
2216 1703 1317
2216 5929 1317
2703 4077 1317
2703 2216 1317
2703 2703 1317
2703 1703 1317
2703 5993 1317
0219 2537 1317
0219 1317 1317
0219 2216 1317
0219 0219 1317
5929 4077 1317
5929 2216 1317
5929 5929 1317
5929 6376 1317
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you can show a reproducible example of your data, and what you have already tried.

Comment: Here's a solution designed for this problem: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Finding-all-single-linked-chains-the-allChains-macro/ta-p/327252

Comment: Reeza,  I've seen this an am having trouble applying it to my situation.  I'll be working on this more today.

Comment: Rezza,  Thank you.  I saw that before but may have missed the importance of it.  It's not immediately clear how to apply it but I'll make it work.  It looks good.